# Merge two multidimensional lists while keeping duplicates if any

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists as follows:

```
    a = [[1,128,"11:18:23.456",2,0,0,"P"],[2,1345,"22:18:23.456",2,1,0,"Q"],[3,1365,"24:18:23.456",1,0,0,"N"]]
    b = [[1,128,"11:18:23.456",2,0,0,"P"],[2,1345,"22:18:23.456",2,1,0,"Q"],[2,1345,"22:18:23.456",2,1,0,"Q"]]
```

I need to merge them (and also sort them based on the second entry in each list (i.e. 128,1345,1365) in such a way that I get the following merged lists:

```
    c_before_sort = [[1,128,"11:18:23.456",2,0,0,"P"],[2,1345,"22:18:23.456",2,1,0,"Q"],[3,1365,"24:18:23.456",1,0,0,"N"],[1,128,"11:18:23.456",2,0,0,"P"],[2,1345,"22:18:23.456",2,1,0,"Q"],[2,1345,"22:18:23.456",2,1,0,"Q"]]
```

and

```
    c_after_sort = [[1,128,"11:18:23.456",2,0,0,"P"],[1,128,"11:18:23.456",2,0,0,"P"],[2,1345,"22:18:23.456",2,1,0,"Q"],[2,1345,"22:18:23.456",2,1,0,"Q"],[2,1345,"22:18:23.456",2,1,0,"Q"],[3,1365,"24:18:23.456",1,0,0,"N"]]
```

Comment: Please visit the [help] before you post a question. It will give you the guidance you need to engage with the community here. This question lacks an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem

Comment: You should switch to Python 3.6+ while you are still learning https://pythonclock.org/

Answer (score 1):

Well this seems easy enough:

```
c = a[:]
c.extend(b)
c.sort(key=lambda lst: lst[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just merge `+` the lists together, and sort based on the second element of each list with [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = [[1,128,"11:18:23.456",2,0,0,"P"],[2,1345,"22:18:23.456",2,1,0,"Q"],[3,1365,"24:18:23.456",1,0,0,"N"]]

b = [[1,128,"11:18:23.456",2,0,0,"P"],[2,1345,"22:18:23.456",2,1,0,"Q"],[2,1345,"22:18:23.456",2,1,0,"Q"]]

c_before_sort = a + b

c_after_sort = sorted(c_before_sort, key = itemgetter(1))
print(c_after_sort)
# [[1, 128, '11:18:23.456', 2, 0, 0, 'P'], [1, 128, '11:18:23.456', 2, 0, 0, 'P'], [2, 1345, '22:18:23.456', 2, 1, 0, 'Q'], [2, 1345, '22:18:23.456', 2, 1, 0, 'Q'], [2, 1345, '22:18:23.456', 2, 1, 0, 'Q'], [3, 1365, '24:18:23.456', 1, 0, 0, 'N']]

# easy peezy lemon squeezy
```